# Calculation the Fourier transform of $f(t)=e^{-|t+1|} \, u(t+3)$

Tags: fourier-transform

The transform of  $f(t)=e^{-|t+1|} \, u(t+3)$ seems to me like mixing the Fourier transform of two functions $f(t)=e^{-a|t|}$ and $f(t)=u(t)$.
I am not sure if I can use convolution or I if I can separate the absolute value.

Comment: The two $f(t)$ in the title and the question are different. which one is correct?

Comment: Have you tried, say, the convolution approach? Any problems with that?

Comment: should i use the convolution of the omega and not time

Answer (score 1):

Consider it as follows:

$$f(t)=f_1(t)+f_2(t)\Rightarrow F(\omega)=F_1(\omega)+F_2(\omega)$$

- $f_1(t)=f(t)\vert_{t>-1}$:
  $$f_1(t)=e^{-(t+1)}u(t+1)$$
- $f_2(t)=f(t)\vert_{t\le-1}$:
  $$f_2(t)=e^{(t+1)}(u(-t-1)-u(-t-3))$$

To calculate $F_1(\omega)$ and $F_2(\omega)$, use $\mathcal{F}\{f(t-t0)\}=e^{-j\omega t_0}\mathcal{F}\{f(t\}$.